# pg_dump from Linux command line

Tags: dump, pg

I am trying to work out a way to perform a PostgreSQL pg_dump of a single DB via RHEL v6.10 command line. Now the system I am working on is that you have to shell into Bash 4.1 first before you get to PSQL. Now I can access the actual PSQL db using the following syntax from the command line which works fine:

'''sudo -u postgres -H --psql -pxxxxx -d db_name'''

If I enter the following syntax from the RHEL command line:

'''sudo su postgres'''

I end up in the bash-4.1 shell. When executing the following command from within the shell: bash-4.1$ pg_dump db_name > /tmp/my_database.sql
I am presented with the following error:

pg_dump: [archiver (db)] connection to database "db_name" failed: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
        Is the server running locally and accepting
        connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?

I am expecting the db to be exported to /tmp/my_database.sql file. I have tried various combinations of commands from both RHEL and bash command lines but cannot achieve the desired outcome. Your assistance would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Connect as 'postgres' user

`sudo -i -u postgres`

Then run pg_dump, e.g.

`pg_dump --blobs --file /your/backup/file/path/backupfilename.pgsql --dbname your_db_name`

After that, you will find your backup file in `/your/backup/file/path/backupfilename.pgsql`

You can add many other options in pg_dump,  [See PostgreSQL Documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/app-pgdump.html)

Comment: Thanks for the post, I did try the pg_dump syntax above and was presented with the follow error message:                                                                                                    pg_dump: unrecognized option '--dbname'
Try "pg_dump --help" for more information.

Comment: What is your PostgreSQL version?

Comment: Hi S. Mohamad,                                                                                                 My PostgreSQL version is: 10.5 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu                                                                                                     Red Hat Enterprise Linux: v6.10                                                                                                  Thank you.

Comment: From the [psql doc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/app-pgdump.html), you can use --dbname in 2 ways: `-d your_db_name` or `--dbname=your_db_name`. Try and let me know

Comment: Hi S. Mohamad, using -d from bash-4.1$ shell, presents the following error:                                                   pg_dump: invalid option -- 'd'
Try "pg_dump --help" for more information.                                                                                          When using --dbname presents the following error: pg_dump: unrecognized option '--dbname'
Try "pg_dump --help" for more information.    Do I have to enter path names?, thank you.

Comment: Can you please show me the full comand you're trying to run?

Comment: Hi S.Mohamad,  I am using the following syntax (x2) from the bash-4.1$ shell:           bash-4.1$ pg_dump --blobs --file /tmp/backupfilename.pgsql --dbname your_db_name  OR bash-4.1$ pg_dump --blobs --file /tmp/backupfilename.pgsql -d your_db_name          either of which are not providing the desired result, thank you.

Comment: Can you please try `pg_dump --blobs --file /tmp/backupfilename.pgsql --dbname=your_db_name`

Comment: Yes, I have tried this command from the bash-4.1$ shell:                                    
bash-4.1$ pg_dump --blobs --file /tmp/backupfilename.pgsql --dbname=db_name
pg_dump: unrecognized option '--dbname=db_name'
Try "pg_dump --help" for more information.
bash-4.1$                                                                                                            
Please Note, to access the DB, I have to enter the following syntax: 
psql -p 54321 db_name                                                                                                 Thank you.

Comment: Ok, try `pg_dump --blobs --file /tmp/backupfilename.pgsql --dbname=your_db_name -p 54321` without doing `psql -p 54321 db_name`